# Implementing multi-tenancy

Tags: database-design, multi-tenant

I have designed my DB and created all the necessary table, such as company, user, department, etc for a user management system.

Now I need to make changes so that  entities/tenants can register in this system.
How can I do it so that each entity registered will be able to create its own companies, its own departments and users etc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.